# What alternatives to Spring+JSF/Facelets exist for web-development in java?

Tags: java, jsf, frameworks, comparison

Let's consider only standard MVC architecture and don't touch [SOFEA](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/sofea_also_known_as_soui).

I'm actually do my web-development with JPA (Hibernate)+Spring+JSF/Faceletes. To use JSF efficiently I also use at least Apache Orchestra and some components library (like Tomahawk or RichFaces).

I've already stepped on a rake several times with jsf. The worst thing I met just yesterday was a bug (or let's better call it 'undocumented feature') in jsf and I spent almost whole day to understand why my simple code didn't worked. It made me think about trying some other stacks or just presentation technology.

What I want to see in answers is several different *complete* sets of technologies (i.e. not just jpa+Spring+jsf/facelets but as in my description - with Orchestra, RichFaces and maybe I've forgotten something else). It'll be great if you can also estimate 'entry threshold' i.e. how difficult to start using the technology (for example, I spent about 1 month before I understood well at least basic principles of jsf).

I'm most interested in Spring+Wicket, Grails, maybe GWT2, stripes. I'm also curious about advantages of Spring+Spring WebFlow+JSF over simple Spring+JSF.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe not the complete answer you have asked for, but you should have a look at http://www.playframework.org/

Comment: you saw a bug and that made you quit? Drop that strategy, it will lead you nowhere.

Comment: Remember that the standard JSF implementation isn't intented to cover everything what you need. It just provides a *basic* set of **minimum required** components based on the raw HTML specification. Using an enhanced component library on top of that is really not *that* bad as you seem to express. What undocumented feature was it by the way? Did you have a good grasp on Servlet API as well? JSF runs on top of it. I've seen too often that JSF related problems/rants are after all caused by ignorance of the Servlet API which JSF uses under the hood.

Comment: @Bozho: no, I don't quit :) I just want to have at least 1 alternative to compare before starting next projects. For example, I've heard that Grails is perfect for simple CRUD projects.

Comment: yes, but then, before your next project ask "my project is this simple, it requires only this and that - what are the best options".

Comment: @BalusC: problem was with validation phase of h:selectMenyListbox. If I have several h:selectMenyListbox inside one form and I want to refresh with ajax only one of them then I get validation exception. When 'non-target' h:selectMenyListbox without any selected item is submitted validation exception occurs...

Comment: did you try `ajaxSingle=true` (or similar, if not using richfaces)

Comment: @BalusC: I updated a bit my qustion to avoid misunderstanding. I didn't mean that it's bad that I had to use Orchestra and RichFaces. More of that, it's very good that RichFaces or Tomahawk exists. I just meant that spring+jsf is incomplete list. I almost sure that Seam (from the 1st answer) also needs some additional component libraries and I want to look at them before learning.

Comment: @Roman: no, Seam doesn't need additional component libraries. Have you seen how *huge* (and complete) it is? Seam is on paper awesome, but it's in my opinion a bit too tied/restricted to a different way of JSF development and you have less freedom to step aside from that way.

Answer (score 1):

[Seam ( JSF + EJB3/JPA)](http://seamframework.org/)
Seam offers benefits of JSF minus the issues associated with it. Since you know JSF the learning curve will be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [ReXSL](http://www.rexsl.com) which uses MVC pattern, but beats JSF by simplicity and testability.